# What's the extended meaning by adding "one" before a noun?

Tags: american-english, modifiers

Example: 
Elaine: "You know those label makers make great gifts, I just gave one for Tim Whatley for Christmas."
Jerry: "!@#$"
Elaine: "Who gave you that?"
Jerry: "One Tim Whatley."

What does the word "one" mean when used as a modifier?

Comment: Do you mean 'I just gave one to Tim Whatley'? And is it the second use of 'one' that you are interested in?

Comment: According to the title of the question, which refers to adding "one" **before a noun**, OP must be asking about "One Tim Whatley". That, @user2167582, means "a person under the name of Tim Whatley" or "somebody known as / called Tim Whatley".

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming it's "One Tim Whatley" that you are interested in.

It means a certain Tim Whatley, who has to this point in time probably not been mentioned.

[one (dictionary.com)](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/one?s=t)

> 6. a certain (often used in naming a person otherwise unknown or undescribed): *One John Smith was chosen.*

---

The other commenter gave an interesting answer which made me check out etymonline. I didn't find anything too useful on that specific meaning of 'one', but it's interesting that [one](https://www.etymonline.com/word/one?ref=etymonline_crossreference) derives from old English 'an' which is an older form of 'a'.

> one (n.)
>
> c. 1200, from Old English an (adjective, pronoun, noun) "one," from
>   Proto-Germanic *ainaz (source also of Old Norse einn, Danish een, Old
>   Frisian an, Dutch een, German ein, Gothic ains), from PIE root *oi-no-
>   "one, unique."

So it could be speculated (at least until someone comes up with evidence to the contrary) that originally a/an Tim Whatley was used to legally specify that it was only one of several possible Tim Whatleys.

Comment: *Interesting in*? ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford lol!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the origin of its use is from old legal jargon (possibly just television-legal, not actual legal) such as "The court hereby alleges that *one* John Doe did, on the night of September 29th, with malice aforethought..."  (Where *that* comes from, I have no idea.  I suspect "Legal" could give you a better answer.)

In the case you're asking about then, it's a form of humor that uses unnecessarily formal and serious language to discuss a trifling matter.  Rather than Jerry just answering the question "Tim Whatley" he uses a (pseudo?) legal construction "One Tim Whatley" as if he is filing charges against Tim for re-gifting.

Comment: 'That' introduces the statement of the charge made by the court. They said _that_ John Doe had committed murder.